# Java Midi Player program

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that plays twinkle twinkle little star using the following guidelines:

a) Experiment with the Midi player and when you feel comfortable how it works do the following:

1. Create a Song class. 
    i) Create a default constructor that sets the name of the song to "Unknown".
    ii) Create a second constructor that takes as input a String for the name of the song, and saves the name in an instance variable in the class.
2. Create an addNote method that takes as input a note, velocity, and duration and saves it somehow in the class (adding the note to array(s) would be a good way to go).
3. Create a playSong method that outputs the name of the song and then plays the notes that have been added to the song.

For example, the following would create a Song named "Test" that plays a middle C for half a second and D for a second:

```
Song test = new Song("Test");
test.addNote(60,127,500);
test.addNote(61,127,1000);
test.playSong();
```

b) Write a main method that uses your Song class to play Twinkle Twinkle Little Star, which starts with the notes: C, C, G, G, A, A, G (half note), F, F, E, E, D, D, C (half note).

I am trying to figure out how to make the playSong method play the notes. I assume I need to use a loop that has the noteOn, sleep, and noteOff in it.

I also do not understand where I am suppose to add the notes, velocities, and durations for each sound. 
I have them in my main method for now because that is what i understood from the guideline but then what do i do with this? ->

```
public void addNote(int note, int velocity, int duration) {
    Info info = new Info(note, velocity, duration);
    addNote.add(info); //do I add the notes, velocities, durations here? 
    //or keep in main?
 }
```

Haven't gotten much sleep trying to do this program so I apologize if these are simple questions. I have done a lot of research (google, books etc) I just haven't found what I was looking for so this is my last resort.

Here is my UPDATED code

```
package song;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class Song {

private String name;
private ArrayList<Info> notes;

public Song() {
    name = "Unknown";
    notes = new ArrayList<Info>();
}

public Song(String nam) {
    name = nam;
}

public class Info {

    int note;
    int velocity;
    int duration;

   private Info(int note, int velocity, int duration) {
        this.note = note;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void addNote(int note, int velocity, int duration) {

    Info info = new Info(note, velocity, duration);
    info.note=note;
    info.velocity=velocity;
    info.duration=duration;
    notes.add(info);

}

public void playSong() {

    Synthesizer synth = null;
    try {
        synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
    }
    try {
        synth.open();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        System.exit(1);
    }

    MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();

    Instrument instruments[] = synth.getAvailableInstruments();
    synth.loadInstrument(instruments[0]);
    channels[0].programChange(74);

    for (Info note : notes){
    channels[0].noteOn(note.note, note.velocity);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(note.duration);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    channels[0].noteOff(note.note);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Song test= new Song("Twinkle Twinkle Little Star");
    test.addNote(60, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(60, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(67, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(67, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(69, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(69, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(67, 127, 1000);
    test.addNote(65, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(65, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(64, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(64, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(62, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(62, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(60, 127, 1000);

    }
}
```

Here is my latest update

```
package song;


public class Song {

private String name;
private ArrayList<Info> notes;

public Song() {
    name = "Unknown";
    notes = new ArrayList<Info>();
}

public Song(String nam) {
    name = nam;
    notes = new ArrayList<Info>();

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public class Info {
    int note;
    int velocity;
    int duration;

    private Info(int note, int velocity, int duration) {
        this.note = note;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}

public void addNote(int note, int velocity, int duration) {

    Info info = new Info(note, velocity, duration);

    notes.add(info);

}

public void playSong() {

    Synthesizer synth = null;
    try {
        synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
    }
    try {
        synth.open();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        System.exit(1);
    }

    MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();

    Instrument instruments[] = synth.getAvailableInstruments();
    synth.loadInstrument(instruments[0]);
    channels[0].programChange(74);

    for (Info note : notes) {
        channels[0].noteOn(note.note, note.velocity);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(note.duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        channels[0].noteOff(note.note);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Song test = new Song("Twinkle Twinkle Little Star");
    test.addNote(60, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(60, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(67, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(67, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(69, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(69, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(67, 127, 1000);
    test.addNote(65, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(65, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(64, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(64, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(62, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(62, 127, 500);
    test.addNote(60, 127, 1000);
    test.playSong();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a different name for your list of notes.  Don't call it `addNote`, because you'll get confused between this and your `addNote` method.  Try just calling it `notes`.  Also, your `playSong` method doesn't need those three parameters.

You could then write something like this inside your `playSong` method.

```
for (Info note : notes) {
    channels[0].noteOn(note.note, note.velocity);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(note.duration);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    channels[0].noteOff(note.note);
}
```

**Update**

I have noticed another problem in your code.  Your constructor for the `Info` class isn't setting the attributes.  So each time you use it, you're just getting an empty object.  It should say something like this.

```
private Info(int note, int velocity, int duration) {
    this.note = note;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.duration = duration;
}
```

Sorry for not noticing this earlier.  Let me know if it fixes your problem.

Also, you'll want to have `notes = new ArrayList<Info>();` in both constructors of the `Song` class.  And you don't want to throw an exception in the `Info` constructor, because you'll just end your program at that point.  Try fixing these things up.  If it still doesn't work, I'll try more stuff later.

Comment: Thank I will I will make those changes!

Comment: Please don't accept my answer until you know that it works - it might discourage someone who knows better than I do from coming along and giving you a better answer.

Comment: Sorry I am new to forum! I just thought the little check meant I liked your answer :)
So I updated my code with the following changes that you suggested but still not getting any output. it doesn't show any errors and builds successfully though

Comment: Just so you know… The Check means the answer you accept as what fixed your problem.  The up arrow means you like it and it was helpful.  It is not uncommon to have useful info from several answer @caustr01

Comment: OK, look I don't think I can fix this for you now.  I'm at work, in an office full of people, and I don't want my computer here to suddenly start playing Twinkle Twinkle Little Star if I solve your problem correctly.  I will have another look at this in a few hours' time, when I'm at home.

Comment: I did the changes you suggested and now it gives me an error on all these lines: Info info = new Info(note, velocity, duration); //says i need a constructor named Info
//says i need to create a field for each of these
 this.note=note;
 this.velocity=velocity;
 this.duration=duration;

Comment: But you HAVE a constructor named `Info`, and you HAVE those three fields in the `Info` class.

Comment: Is it possible that you have your `{` and `}` in the wrong places?

Comment: Yes I know doesn't make sense. Im double checking everything and it doesn't look like an brackets are misplaced or in the wrong area. Ive posted my latest update

Comment: You removed the constructor from `Info`, and you didn't replace it with my version.  Paste my version of the `Info` constructor  (the second grey box in my answer) inside the definition of the `Info` class.

Comment: Sorry I somehow missed that ! or overread it. I fixed all of that so the only errors I am getting is with the 
this.note=note; ...etc still getting the field error

Comment: If you're talking about the lines inside the `addNote` method, then just remove those three lines.  You don't want them.

Comment: Okay well its still not playing the music :/ I might have to just make do with what I have because I need to turn it in. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I'll be home in about two hours.  I'll be able to fix it for you then.  Does that give you enough time?

Comment: two hours for me is midnight which is when the assignment is due so probably not. :/ the teacher is pretty lenient though so if I turned in all my work and then later updated him that i fixed my code he will probably give me full credit. I would def like to figure this program out.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to figure it out too, whether it ends up being any use to you or not.  I'm sure it's just some small detail that's missing, and I'm sure your professor will give you credit for what you _have_ been able to achieve.  I will post later.

Comment: Your problem is that you never called `playSong`.  Add `test.playSong();` to the end of `main`, and this will work!  It doesn't sound quite right - there's not enough of a pause between each note.  But it should be good enough to earn you full marks for the assignment.  Good luck!

Comment: For some reason it is still not playing for me. I am pretty sure I have done everything correctly as you told me to do. I updated my code above do I have what you have?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment for a while.  Yes, I pasted exactly what you have above into a new class.  I had to add some imports to get it to compile, of course.  But I ran it.  It certainly played the tune.  I can't imagine what you might've done wrong, other than the obvious things like muting your speakers.

Comment: ... and I can't imagine your professor deducting any marks, when you hand in a program that works perfectly on _my_ computer, even if for whatever reason, it doesn't work on yours.

Comment: omg i got it to work! not sure what was wrong yesterday but ran it today and it worked just fine! THank you!!